# Year-Over-Year Change or Previous Year Values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, table-plus

I have a table that looks something like this

| Date | Number of products | Department | Sub-Department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2019 | 10 | A | Ax |
| 01-01-2019 | 4 | A | Ay |
| 02-01-2019 | 14 | B | By |
| 02-01-2019 | 15 | A | Ay |

The table contain data from 2018 to current date. For each date, there are multiple rows for each department and sub-department.

I want to create a column that will tell me the number of products from a year ago, grouped by date, department, sub-department and other columns that I have.

Comment: What is your expected result set for your example data? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DavidDenenberg Expected result would be the exact same table with an extra column that has the value for previous year's number of products. I have been searching for solutions until now, but most of them have the data on a month or year level, so they use the lag window function to get the value.

Comment: And what is your date format?  I can't even tell what the data means.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first column is a date, you can use window functions:

```
select date, department, sub_department, num_products,
       max(num_products) over (partition by department, sub_department
                               order by date
                               range between interval 1 year preceding and interval 1 year preceding
                              ) as num_products_1_year_ago
from t;
```